# Grails: working offline with snapshot dependencies

Tags: grails, ivy, snapshot

I am using some plugins which depend on snapshot versions of other plugins.
As I understand, Ivy tries to fetch the newest version of these plugins every time you start grails. If Ivy does not succeed, grails will not start :-(

As I like to develop offline, I am now looking for a way which lets me avoid this behaviour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pull them down and store them on your machine using a local repository and comment out any remote repositories. [Here is some documentation.](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.2%20Dependency%20Repositories) Scroll down to "local resolvers"